# Identify of which observable the error belongs for a list of observables

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, observable

```
const obs1$ = this.service.getAllSources();
const obs2$ = this.service.getWidgetById(1);

combineLatest([obs1$, obs2$])
   .subscribe(pair => {
      const sources = pair[0];
      const widget = pair[1];
      // do stuff
   }, err => {
       // err can be from first or second observable, but which?    
       if (err.status === 404) {
          // here I need to know for which observable the error is ocurred ?!?!
          this.utilsService.alert('Widget with id 1 not found');
       }
       
       if (err.status === 500) {
          // here, I need to know from which observable occured
       }
   });
```

From the backend I never send a `404 status` for getting a list, so, in this case, I can be sure that `404` came from second observable only. But if I want to have another logic inside `error` method, I'll need to know from which observable it's occured. How I can do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could wrap each observable in `catchError` and hadle them respectively:

```
combineLatest([
obs1$.pipe(catchError(e => ...)), 
obs2$.pipe(catchError(e => ...)),
]).subscribe(...)
```

or you could mark the errors and handle them in the `subscribe`. smth like

```
obs1$.pipe(catchError(e => throwError({originalError: e, source: 'whatever you want'}))),
```